# How can I parse the string to Double

Tags: java, android

I want to parse 78 into double variable where 78 is stored as a String

I used below code to parse.

```
Double.parseDouble(78);
```

It display's Exception Error java.lang.NumberFormatException

Plz tell me How can I parse String 78 into double

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html a lot of problems like these can be solved by using the Reference available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well what you passed was an integer and not a string.

To use it do this:

```
Double.parseDouble("78");
```

Comment: Or, if you actually wanted to convert an integer into a double... `double d = 78;` ...

Comment: Sorry, I give only example here, I dont pass 78 in my real code I passed the String variable there

Comment: @Mohit. well on SO you should post your complete code or else you will get answers like this (or somewhat complete)

Comment: Probably the string is ending up containing something other than the two digits for whatever reason? The code would probably help, yes.

Comment: I have a suspicion that there is a leading or trailing space.  It could be something more exotic, but its usually the simple things.

Comment: Problem is solved.....Problem is from api side...they are give response with string sometime means they are give response like("aaa"). So it is not problem from coding side...You all are right and I am heartily Thankful of u all...and Also sorry that I waste valuable time of u all.

Comment: `String a = "78"; Double b = Double.parseDouble(a);System.out.println(b);` works fine..Where is the incompleteness in this??

Comment: @KoustavRay the question was edited after the fact. Now the answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be `Double.parseDouble(78)` but `Double.parseDouble("78")` instead.

In that case it shouldn't give you any exception.

Comment: Sorry, I give only example here, I dont pass 78 in my real code I passed the String variable there

Answer (score 2):

pass it as `String`

```
Double.parseDouble("78");
```

Comment: Sorry, I give only example here, I dont pass 78 in my real code I passed the String variable there

Comment: Can you tell me what string it passes exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put quotes around your parameter.

```
Double.parseDouble("78");
```

Comment: Sorry, I give only example here, I dont pass 78 in my real code I passed the String variable there

Comment: Can you post the code for that string conversion you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I strongly suspect that the value of the string variable you're passing in actually *isn't* a valid number. I suggest you log the Unicode value of each character, so you can see *exactly* what's in there.

The code you've given (passing the string "78") should be absolutely fine... but you may have some extra, invisible characters in your real string. Logging the exact values should make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

before you parse your string variable , use the method `trim()` in order to be sure that your string contain only numbers , , try this :

```
myStringToParse = myStringToParse.trim();
Double.parseDouble(myStringToParse);
```